# Remove already added class when value it different

Tags: javascript

This is a simple issue that I am having. I am new to javascript and trying to create a BMI calculator with a color code to indicate the BMI result. I am adding a class to the color based on the BMI result. for eg. I am adding "active" class to the "normal" div when the BMI is normal. Same for others. But if a class is added I can not remove it when other is selected.
How can I fix it?

```js
const hFeet = document.querySelector("#hFeet");
const hInch = document.querySelector("#hInch");
const wKg = document.querySelector("#wKg");
const submit = document.querySelector("#submit");
const result = document.querySelector("#result_area");
const wStatus = document.querySelector("#wst");

submit.addEventListener("click", bmiFunc);

function bmiFunc(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const height = hFeet.value * 0.3048 + hInch.value * 0.0254;
  const weight = wKg.value;
  const calculation = weight / Math.pow(height, 2);
  const final = calculation.toFixed(2);
  result.innerHTML = final;

  if (final < 16) {
    wStatus.innerHTML = "Severe Thinness";
    document.querySelector(".thin1").classList.add("active");
  } else if (final >= 16 && final < 17) {
    wStatus.innerHTML = "Moderate Thinness";
    document.querySelector(".thin2").classList.add("active");
  } else if (final >= 17 && final < 18.5) {
    wStatus.innerHTML = "Mild Thinness";
    document.querySelector(".thin3").classList.add("active");
  } else if (final > 18.5 && final <= 25) {
    wStatus.innerHTML = "Normal";
    document.querySelector(".norm1").classList.add("active");
  } else if (final > 25 && final <= 30) {
    wStatus.innerHTML = "Overweight";
    document.querySelector(".ow1").classList.add("active");
  } else if (final > 30 && final <= 35) {
    wStatus.innerHTML = "Obese Class I";
    document.querySelector(".obs1").classList.add("active");
  } else if (final >= 35 && final <= 40) {
    wStatus.innerHTML = "Mild Thinness";
    document.querySelector(".obs2").classList.add("active");
  } else if (final > 40) {
    wStatus.innerHTML = "Mild Thinness";
    document.querySelector(".obs3").classList.add("active");
  }
}
```

```css
.color .column {
  height: 30px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.clm_thin .thin1 {
  background: #ff9595;
}

.clm_thin .thin2 {
  background: #ffafaf;
}

.clm_thin .thin3 {
  background: #ffdab6;
}

.clm_normal .norm1 {
  background: #4e9b00;
}

.clm_overWeight .ow1 {
  background: #f5f500;
}

.clm_obesity .obs1 {
  background: #ff7474;
}

.clm_obesity .obs2 {
  background: #ff3e3e;
}

.clm_obesity .obs3 {
  background: #db0000;
}

.active {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.bmi_scale {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300italic,700,700italic" />
  <!-- CSS Reset -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.css" />
  <!-- Milligram CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/milligram/1.4.1/milligram.css" />
  <!-- You should properly set the path from the main file. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />
  <title>BMI calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="bmi_wrapper">
          <div class="bmi_form">
            <form action="">
              <div class="bmi_height">
                <h3>Your Height:</h3>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="column">
                    <input type="text" name="hFeet" id="hFeet" />
                    <label for="hFeet">feet</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="column">
                    <input type="text" name="hInch" id="hInch" />
                    <label for="hInch">inchs</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- bmi_height -->
              <div class="bmi_weight">
                <h3>Your weight:</h3>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="column">
                    <input type="text" name="wKg" id="wKg" />
                    <label for="wKg">Kg</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- bmi_weight -->
              <div class="bmi_btn">
                <input type="submit" value="Calculate BMI" id="submit" />
              </div>
              <!-- bmi_btn -->
            </form>
          </div>
          <!-- bmi_form -->
          <div class="bmi_result">
            <div class="bmi">Your BMI is: <span id="result_area">0</span> kg/m<sup>2</sup></div>
            <div class="wStatus">Weight Status: <span id="wst"></span></div>
          </div>

          <!-- bmi_result -->
          <div class="bmi_scale">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="column clm_thin">
                <div class="row color">
                  <div class="column thin1 column-50"></div>
                  <div class="column thin2 column-25"></div>
                  <div class="column thin3 column-25"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- column_thin -->
              <div class="column clm_normal">
                <div class="row color">
                  <div class="column norm1"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- column_normal -->
              <div class="column clm_overWeight">
                <div class="row color">
                  <div class="column ow1"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column clm_obesity">
                <div class="row color">
                  <div class="column obs1"></div>
                  <div class="column obs2"></div>
                  <div class="column obs3"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- bmi_scale -->
        </div>
        <!-- bmi_wrapper -->
      </div>
      <!-- column -->
    </div>
    <!-- row -->
  </div>
  <!-- container -->

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the jsfiddle link
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rony747/rankfxLu/1/)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest you can do is reset beforehand the class from your ".active":

In the lack of a more descriptive className - use `.bmi_scale .column` to target the "columns"

```js
document.querySelector(".bmi_scale .column.active").classList.remove("active");

// if (final < 16) { etc.....
```

Or, if needed for some case - from all:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".bmi_scale .column").forEach(el => {
  el.classList.remove("active")
});

// if (final < 16) { etc.....
```